# Cannot get my JS code running on codepen.io, Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

`see url` http://codepen.io/shihanrehman/pen/JGJpmV?editors=101

I need the few lines of code outputted to the window, this is functional programming.

Comment: I saw it working, outputting result as 90

Comment: @Midhun No, it's not working

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what to ask and how.

Answer (score 0):

`dogs` isn't a function, it's an array of objects. Replace the last line with `document.body.innerHTML += dogs[0].name;`.

Answer (score 0):

As said, dogs is not a function -

This will show the object:

```
document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(dogs);
```

and this will show their names:

```js
var animals = [
  {name: 'Fluffykins', species: 'rabbit'},
  {name: 'Caro', species: 'dog'},
  {name: "Hamilton", species: 'dog'},
  {name: "Harold", species: 'fish'},
  {name: "Ursula", species: 'cat'},
  {name: 'Jimmy', species: 'fish'}
];

var dogs = animals.filter(function(animal){
  return animal.species === 'dog'
});

document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>Dogs:" + dogs.map(function(dog) {
  return dog.name;
});
```